# "set -xe" in fish shell

Tags: bash, fish

In bash, invoking `set -x` at the beginning of a script causes the commands to be printed on stdout while the script is executing. What's the equivalent syntax for the [fish shell](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/beta.html)?

Comment: I think it's one of those deal-braking features between bash and fish.

Answer (score 1):

Fish's `set` command doesn't have that option.

However you could wrap `set` in your shell script. This would print the same format of output you're used to when placed at the top of a script.

`function set; echo + set $argv; builtin set $argv; end`

Alternatively, the function command has an `--on-variable` option that allows you to monitor particular variables for changes and have the function called automatically.

Or you can execute your fish script with fish -d 3 `script.fish`. This will print some tracing information.